# selenium element location implementation

Tags: dom, selenium

This could sound like a pretty basic question, but I could not find a proper answer to my question. How does Selenium element location implementation work? For example:- When doing `findElement` by ID, does selenium(some engine or implementation) traverse the entire DOM? I assume it does.

In that case how is `findElement` by ID faster than `findElement` by Xpath. Because if I provide an Xpath like `//input[@id='']` then Selenium (some engine or implementation) will not traverse the entire DOM and directly search for input elements hence resulting a faster search.

Comment: On google.com, measured the time to findElement by ID and Xpath for the search button. And as expected Xpath took less time.

Comment: driver.get("http://www.google.com");
   
   Thread.sleep(5000);

   long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

   WebElement btnSearch = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfba"));

   long estimatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

   System.out.println(estimatedTime);

   startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

   btnSearch = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='gbqfba']"));

   estimatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

   System.out.println(estimatedTime);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation for xpath and id etc (all Bys) are different depending on which browser you are running against, certain browsers will run some bys faster than others because they have native support for searching via that way when others require selenium to have to fudge the implementation so it works. An example of this is xpath which is not implemented natively in IE if i remember correctly so using xpath there is significantly slower than id.

Comment: Thank you both for the answers. The code i posted above was actually tested on Firefox. I am now trying to find out the various browser implementations for native support for location strategies. If you have any prior info on that, please post.

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver closely models the underlying Javascript implementation of the browser.

According to the W3C WebDriver Draft, for example, a locator by ID should be functionally equivalent to the javascript `document.getElementById()` call.

Implementations of WebDriver for different browsers should use the native support for the location strategies such as xpath. If native support is not available, a pure JS implementation may be used. Due to the varied range of browsers and their native implementations, the performance of each location strategy will be different across each combination of browser and locator strategy.

*References, and further reading:*

[WebDriver  - W3C Editor's Draft - Element Location Strategies](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webdriver/raw-file/tip/webdriver-spec.html#element-location-strategies)

[Selenium Webdriver Architecture - *Simon Stewart*](http://www.aosabook.org/en/selenium.html)